# Getting a standalone foward slash to be replaced, surrounded by span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to be able to detect a " / " within a `h1` tag, and replace it surrounded with `<span class="slash"></span>`, where `.slash` will act as a separator.

```js
var div = $('h1');
div.html(div.html().replace(/\//g, '<span class="slash">/</span>'));
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

span.slash {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 17px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
   Sector: Hospitality / Year: 2018 / Review: October 2018
</h1>
```

I thought I would be able to achieve this with a simple regex. But I get an unexpected output:

```
<h1>
  Sector: Hospitality 
      <span class="slash">/ Year: 2018 
        <span class="slash">/ Review: October 2018
        </span>
      </span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put it into a `$('document').ready(function() { ... });`:

(Note: I added a background color to the `span` to make the working replacement more obvious)

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var div = $('h1');
  div.html(div.html().replace(/\//g, '<span class="slash">/</span>'));
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

span.slash {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 17px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  Sector: Hospitality / Year: 2018 / Review: October 2018
</h1>
```